# Assign values to a vector of strings

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a cell array of strings and I need to assign them a value.

```
interval = {'Active', 'Active', 'Active', 'Active', 'Active', 'Active', 'Rest', ...
'Rest', 'Rest', 'Rest','Active', 'Active', 'Active', 'Active'}
```

How do I assign a value of 1 to Active and 0 to Rest?
I tried using this:

```
intervalNum = zeros(length(interval), 1); 

for n = 1:length(interval) 
   if interval(n) == 'Active'
      i = 1;
   else
      i = 0;
   end
   intervalNum(n) = i; 
end
```

But it shows an error: 
Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

I figured the error is due to the if statement "if interval(n) == "Active"" but can't figure out what is wrong.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: `intervalNum = cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x, 'Active'), interval)` ? With you appropach, change the `if` condition to `strcmp(interval{n}, 'Active')`

Comment: to compare string you need the `strcmp` function

Comment: Or `intervalnum(strcmp('Active',interval))=1;` after initialization with `zeros`

Comment: Cell indexing is done with `{}`.

Comment: @Jørgen What does cell indexing has to do with this?

Comment: @BillBokeey as others have noted `interval` is a cell array, if you were to use to for loop approach you would use cell indexing. But your method is way smarter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to compare strings, you need to use the strcmp function as specified here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html

```
for n = 1:length(interval) 
   if strcmp(interval{n},'Active')
      i = 1;
   else
      i = 0;
   end
   intervalNum(n) = i; 
end
```

Or even better, remove the loop and use the method Luis Mendo suggested:

```
intervalNum = cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x, 'Active'), interval)

intervalNum = ismember(interval, 'Active'); %Alternative provided by Luis Mendo
```

Or the method BillBokeey suggested:

```
intervalnum(strcmp('Active',interval))=1
```

Comment: Or `intervalNum = ismember(interval, 'Active');`

Comment: Thanks guys! That helped me out a lot.